# $\dim(R/I(Y_1) \cap I(Y_2))= \dim R/I(Y_1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be two distinct points in a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n.$ Also let $I(Y_1)$ and $I(Y_2)$ be the corresponding homogeneous ideals in $R=K[X_0,\ldots,X_n].$ Then how can I show that $\dim(R/I(Y_1) \cap I(Y_2))= \dim R/I(Y_1)$ without looking at the dimension of the projective algebraic sets.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Any prime ideal containing a intersection of two ideals, contains one of them.

Comment: Right.. actually If it contains $I(Y_2)$ then $\text{dim}R/I(Y_2)= \text{dim}(R/(I(Y_1)\cap I(Y_2))$ but they are all equal.

Comment: @Panja I suppose you know what's the height of the ideals $I(Y_i)$.

Comment: Yes I know @ user26857